# Send a command on multiple devices

Tags: perl

I have this script to read a devices list and send a command. but currently it reads only the first device and sends it the command, ignoring the rest. What have I missed?

```
#!\usr\bin\Perl\bin\perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use NET::SSH2;
use MIME::Base64;
my $host = "C:/temp/devices.txt"; # input file
my $user = "XXX"; # your account
my $pass = "XXXXXX"; # your password  64 bit mime
my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
my $result = "C:/temp/result.txt"; # output file
$ssh2->debug(1); # debug on/off
open(List, '<', "$host") or die "$!";
while(<List>) {
    chomp $_;
    $ssh2->connect("$_") or die "Unable to connect host $@ \n";
    my $dp=decode_base64("$pass");
    $ssh2->auth_password("$user","$dp");
    my $chan = $ssh2->channel();
    $chan->exec('sh run');
    my $buflen =100000;
    my $buf = '0' x $buflen;
    my $read = $chan->read($buf, $buflen );
    warn 'More than ', $buflen, ' characters in listing' if $read >= $buflen;
    open OUTPUT, ">", "$result";
    print OUTPUT "HOST: $_\n\n";
    print OUTPUT "$buf\n";
    print OUTPUT "\n\n\n";
    print OUTPUT
    close (List);
    $chan->close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
close(List);
```

should be after the closing bracket.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't be closing your `List` filehandle inside of your while loop. Move the `close (List);` line to after the close brace:

```
open(List, '<', "$host") or die "$!";
while(<List>) {
    # ⋮
}
close (List);
```

Comment: thanks, that solved my primary issue, now I have the script unable connect to the second and the rest of the devices on the list

Answer (score 4):

You're closing your filehandle inside the `while()` loop. Move `close(List)` so it's outside of the `while()`:

```
while(<List>) {
    ...
}
close(List);
```

**Edit**: I just noticed that you're also doing this within your `while()` loop:

```
open OUTPUT, ">", "$result";
```

This will cause your output file to be overwritten each time through the loop, so it will only have the last command's results in it. You could either move the `open() / close()` outside of the loop, or open the file in append mode:

```
open OUTPUT, '>>', $result;
```

You're also not checking to see if the `open()` succeeds; you should put `or die $!` at the end of your `open()` statement.

Comment: thanks, this solved the first issue. reading second device list but now unable to connect to the second device getting error "unable connect to the host"